# Query Geofire for top X number of records in the area?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, firebase, ionic-framework, geofire

Trying to wrap my head around Geofire, so for the time being lets say my firebase database ranks bars all over the U.S.  My firebase query in this case would return a rated list of the top 100 bars in the country.  If the map is zoomed out to the whole country could Geofire return only the top 100 bars in the country?  In addition if the map were zoomed into say New York, could Geofire also only return the top 100 in New York?  In other words, I want to return the top 100 given the viewing area, where the list obviously changes as the list moves around. Can it handle this?  If so, is the an example out there I can see?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use geoquery to set center and radius for zooming in and out

```html
var geoQuery = geoFire.query({
  center: [10.38, 2.41],
  radius: 10.5
});

var center = geoQuery.center();  // center === [10.38, 2.41]
var radius = geoQuery.radius();  // radius === 10.5

geoQuery.updateCriteria({
  center: [-50.83, 100.19],
  radius: 5
});

center = geoQuery.center();  // center === [-50.83, 100.19]
radius = geoQuery.radius();  // radius === 5

geoQuery.updateCriteria({
  radius: 7
});

center = geoQuery.center();  // center === [-50.83, 100.19]
radius = geoQuery.radius();  // radius === 7
```

for top 100 you can use approach like when you receive 100 element for current geoQery, call cancel.

```html
var geoQuery = geoFire.query({
  center: [10.38, 2.41],
  radius: 10.5
});

var bars = []

var onKeyExitedRegistration = geoQuery.on("key_exited", function(key, location, distance) {
  console.log(key + " exited query to " + location + " (" + distance + " km from center)");
  bars.push(key);
  if(bars.length>=100)
  {
    geoQuery.cancel();
  }
});
```

[reference doc](https://github.com/firebase/geofire-js/blob/master/docs/reference.md)

Comment: Thanks for the help.  So the example you gave limits the number of "bars" displayed to 100, but could it be used to return the top 100 in that area? If there is 10,000 bars in New York, we only want to show the top 100.  in other words, how are the 100 records in the bars array ordered? or is the query simply stopping at 100 regardless of the "rank" we want to order by.  Conversely can we load the bars array with the top 100 bars given an area?

Comment: geofire can only give the key of your record, you can then use that key to query other record. so to get ranking information, you will have to query all the keys out within the radius then do a ranking comparison. You can put ranking info in the key i.e. (firebase_key_rank), and rank the key before query 10k record, so you only query 100 record, but you still need to query all 10k key out.